# Object Orientation errors

Tags: python

Methods:

– Constructor takes in no argument.

– get_stock_names(): returns a list of strings that represents the names of all food items in the stock.

– has_stock(name): returns True if a food item’s name is found in stock.

– load(food): add the food object to stock.

– sell(name): returns the item to be sold. The item to be sold is the first food item in the stock list that matches the input name. Remember to remove the sold food item from stock. If the item name does not match any in the list, return None.

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self,name,nutrition,good_until):
        self.name = name
        self.nutrition = nutrition
        self.good_until = good_until
        self.age = 0

class FermentedFood(Food):
    def __init__(self,name,nutrition,good_after,good_until):
        super().__init__(name,nutrition,good_until)
        self.good_after = good_after
```

This is previously define

```
class VendingMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = []
    def get_stock_names(self):
        return [i.name for i in self.obj]
    def has_stock(self,name):  
        return  name in [i.name for i in self.obj]
    def load(self,food):
        self.obj.append(food)
        return self.obj
    def sell(self,name):  
        for food in self.obj:
            if food.name == name:
                self.obj.remove(food)
                return food
        return None

machine = VendingMachine()
apple = Food("apple", 70, 7)
banana = Food("banana", 100, 4)
yoghurt = FermentedFood("yoghurt", 50, 0, 10)
machine.load(banana)
machine.load(apple)
machine.load(yoghurt)
machine.load(apple)
print(machine.get_stock_names())  #["banana", "apple", "yoghurt", "apple"])
print(machine.has_stock("apple"))
print(machine.sell("apple")) #True
print(machine.get_stock_names()) ##Since apple is sold so `["banana", "yoghurt", "apple"]`
```

The error here is in the load.

As each fruit is sold in the list at the end,

```
machine.sell("banana") #banana
machine.get_stock_names() #[]
machine.load(banana) #None
```

I didn't get `None` for `machine.load(banana)`

I tried to change the definition of load to this

```
def load(self,food):
        if self.get_stock_names == []:
            return None
        else:
            self.obj.append(food)
            return self.obj
```

But it I end up not getting the results for the other testes

Comment: Your original load method don't invoke get_stock_names. But a normal check will be 'if not self.get_stock_names():return None'. Still, check if remove do the job. The obj.pop(obs.index(name)) is not OK?(in a try-else, the name may not be on your list)

Comment: @cox pop can only be be used for integer

Comment: and if not self.get_stock_names(): changes the other definition as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The error here is in the load.

Your load method has no error. It does `self.obj.append(food)` and like you stated:

> – load(food): add the food object to stock.

that is exactly what it should do so that is all right.

---

> I didn't get None for machine.load(banana)

You are not supposed to (I'm not sure why you expect it to return `None`). See here why

```
def load(self,food):
    self.obj.append(food)
    return self.obj
```

Your load method returns a list to which `food` was appended. Because you passed in banana as parameter, it appends that to the list. After that it returns the list (with the new food object appended).

`load()` will never return `None` because it returns the list object, and that exists because it was created when the vending machine object was created.
Even if it is empty, it still exists as a list, therefore it would not be `None` but `[]`.

If even if the list was empty and you did something like `machine.load(None)` it would simply append `None` to the list and return `[None]`.

Even though you asked no real question, I hope this will help you fix the issue.